# ImageView not display (android)

Tags: android

My ImageView is not displaying anything and I have no idea why.  The file it is using is located in the each drawable folder and is a .tiff file.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon, parent, false);

    ImageView m = new ImageView(getActivity());
    m.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_dl_256);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.l1);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());

    tr.addView(m);
    tl.addView(tr);

    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like .tiff is not a supported media format: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

You're probably going to need to convert those to .png or one of the other core formats if you want to just drop it into the drawables folders.

Comment: @Allan [Maybe this will help you](http://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/source/browse/). Calvin is right .tiff is not supported natively